# Show that the mapping $x\rightarrow x^{-1}$ of $G$ onto $G$ is an isomorphism iff $G$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Question : Show that the mapping $x\rightarrow x^{-1}$ of $G$ onto $G$ is an isomorphism iff $G$ is abelian, $x\in G $

I need some pointers for proving this .

Comment: What do you mean by an isomorphism? ;P

Comment: It's bijective by definition of a group. So when is the mapping a group homomorphism?

Comment: Do you know what $(ab)^{-1}$ is in general? What does it need to be if $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is to be a group homomorphism?

Comment: @awllower : a mapping will be called isomorphism if it is one-one and onto and preserves the composition

Comment: And then you can continue by other comments! I was just trying to hint. Sorry if this causes confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $\varphi: G\to G$, with $\varphi(a) = a^{-1}$, $\varphi$ is bijective by the definition of a group.

That leaves us only to consider whether $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism: we need for $$\varphi(ab) = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1} = \varphi(b)\varphi(a) = \varphi(a)\varphi(b)$$

Now, why will the rightmost equality hold if and only if the group with elements $a, b$ is abelian?

Comment: ok, so only when $G$ is abelian that we can write $\varphi(b) \varphi(a) =\varphi(a) \varphi(b)$ is this the reason why $G$ must be abelian ?

Comment: @Aman Yes, indeed. Commutativity is a necessary and sufficient condition for $\varphi$ to be an isomorphism.

Comment: Got it !! Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome, Aman!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback! +1 It is fun to spool up past areas 9i have so many that need work)! :-)

Comment: @amWhy $~~+^+_+~~$

Answer (score 2):

A direct answer comes from considering $\varphi\colon G\to G$, $\varphi(x)=x^{-1}$ and imposing it's a homomorphism:
$$
\varphi(x)\varphi(y)=\varphi(xy)
$$
that is,
$$
x^{-1}y^{-1}=(xy)^{-1}
$$
which becomes
$$
x^{-1}y^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}.
$$
Set $x=a^{-1}$ and $y=b^{-1}$.