# Prove $G$ is abelian if $f(f(x)) = x$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $f$ an automorphism such that
>
> 1. $f(f(x)) = x$, and
> 2. $f(x) = x$ if and only if $x=e$.
>
> Prove that $G$ is abelian and $f(x) = x^{-1}$.

My attempt:

Since $f(f(x)) = x$, we can divide the elements of $G$ (except e) into pairs $(a,b)$ such that $f(a)=b$ and $f(b)=a$. So $G$ has odd order. What to do next.. Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Can you clarify what 'only $f(e)=e$' means? Do you mean that the only solution to $f(x)=x$ is $x=e$ ?

Comment: @RagibZaman Yes $e$ is the only fixed point.

Comment: Very similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482116/show-that-the-mapping-x-rightarrow-x-1-of-g-onto-g-is-an-isomorphism-if

Comment: what is  a counter example if $G$ is not a finite group?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Let $G$ be the free group generated by $\{a,b\}$ and consider the automorphism $f$ induced by $f(a)=b$ and $f(b)=a$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The map $h : G \to G$, $h(x) = f(x) x^{-1}$ is injective, because the only fixed point of $f$ is $e$. So it's injective, and therefore surjective because $G$ is finite. So you can write any $y \in G$ as $y = h(x) = f(x) x^{-1}$. But then $$f(y) = f(f(x)) f(x)^{-1} = x f(x)^{-1} = \left( f(x) x^{-1} \right)^{-1} = y^{-1}$$

And this for all $y \in G$. Now it's a standard argument that if $f(x) = x^{-1}$ is a homomorphism, then the group is abelian: $xy = (y^{-1} x^{-1})^{-1} = (y^{-1})^{-1} (x^{-1})^{-1} = yx$.

Comment: Why does $x(f(x))^{-1} = (f(x))^{-1}x$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks for the solution. But is there any logic why you chose such a mapping. Clearly it works, but how does one come up with such an analysis.

Comment: @user143010: Since we're not given much data, I wanted to prove that $f(x) x$ is a fixpoint of $f$ (which would have been enough). In general I couldn't, but then if you apply $f$ to that you almost get the inverse. And I had to use somewhere that $G$ is finite...

Comment: In your pre-edit version! ;-)

Comment: Ah right I added the $\left( \cdot \right)^{-1}$, but I thought I had been quick enough :)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks again for furthur explaining..

Comment: Actually, it may be that my little 'droid rendered your $\LaTeX$ badly; happens all the time.  Nice proof! +1!

Comment: So it wasn't my 'droid!  Again, nice work!

Comment: @NajibIdrissi If you got the idea for this from [the site you posted](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Fixed-point-free_involution_on_finite_group_is_inverse_map), I think you should cite it.